# CakePHP cannot connect to Postgres. Pgadmin4 can however

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

CakePHP3 cannot connect to my PostgreSQL database.

My setup is the following:

- Windows 10 host
- CentOS7 Virtualbox VM guest

  - PostgreSQL 9.6
  - Apache 2.4
  - PHP 7

Error:

CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.

Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I've tried to specify `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.2.31` as my host value in app.php. They all give out the same error.

All is not lost, I can reach PostgreSQL in the following manners:

- connecting to the server via my workstation using Pgadmin4
- connected via SSH, I can connect via using psql

`[me@localhost ~]$ psql -U my_user -h 127.0.0.1 -d my_db`

**Update #1**

default database configuration

```
'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres',
            'persistent' => true,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            /**
             * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
             * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
             * the following line and set the port accordingly
             */
            //'port' => 5432,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'database' => 'my_db',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,

            /**
             * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
             * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
             * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
             * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
             * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
             * manipulated before being executed.
             */
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

            /**
             * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
             * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
             * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
             * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
             * which is the recommended value in production environments
             */
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],

            //'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ]
```

**Update #2**

`phpinfo` data regarding PostgreSQL

```
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql, pgsql, sqlite 

pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.15
Module version  7.0.13
Revision    $Id: f9b0c62eba234361d62f16fcbaaa120353ab5175 $ 

pgsql
PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.15
PostgreSQL(libpq)   PostgreSQL 9.2.15 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4), 64-bit
Multibyte character support     enabled
SSL support     enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
```

**Update #3**

While having `tcpdump` running:
`tcpdump -i lo port 5432 -w pg.cap`

I got some packets when I used `psql`. However, I don't get any packets when accessing my site through CakePHP.

`pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Comment: Show your database configuration `DATABASE_CONFIG` class.

Comment: Step #1 - check your credentials in datasource setup and use the same that works on command line.

Comment: I'm using the same working credentials from PgAdmin being used on my workstation.

Comment: It seems your are using Redhat, please try this . Apache is by default blocked to access database servers - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Booleans-Configuring_Booleans.html

Comment: Actually, I'm using CentOs7, which is based off RHEL... does it still apply?

Comment: Try `getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db` - what it returns? With respect to https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans this setting still apply for Centos.

Comment: That was it. I can now connect to Postgres. Let me know if you want to supply an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Answer added for the other users who will will be looking for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux distributions based on RedHat there is a configuration value `httpd_can_network_connect_db` that enables / disables Apache to connect to database servers. In default state this value is set to `off` what means that Appache **is not allowed** to connect.

To check whether is it allowed on your box:

```
getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
```

and if it returns `off` you should allow it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

(`-P` make this setting persistent across reboots)

For more information please see [SELinux Booleans](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans) and [⁠Configuring Booleans](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Booleans-Configuring_Booleans.html).

Comment: Odd. I've had to do this twice on VMs and both of them, upon reboot, I get the following message: failed to load SELinux policy. To get around this, I need to put selinux=0 before booting the VM...